# How can i erase flash sector on stm32f0308-disco

Tags: stm32

I'm using stm32f0308-disco development card and i need to write new datas to flash for that i need the clean up the sector. But in hal libraries there is no such a function called FLASH_Erase_Sector(). How can i clear the flash?

```
void writeToFlash(uint32_t SoC_Address) {
    HAL_FLASH_Unlock();
    for (int i = 1; i < 31; i++) {
        HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_WORD, SoC_Address, readedData[i]);
        SoC_Address = SoC_Address + 4;
    }
    HAL_FLASH_Lock();
}
```

This is my code for writing to flash

edit:
i try this code to erase flash

```
erase_pages.PageAddress = SoC_Address;
    erase_pages.NbPages = 1;
    erase_pages.TypeErase = FLASH_TYPEERASE_PAGES;
    uint32_t * Error = 0;

    HAL_FLASH_Unlock ();
    HAL_FLASHEx_Erase (&erase_pages, Error);
    HAL_FLASH_Lock ();
```

but when gets in to **HAL_FLASHEx_Erase (&erase_pages, Error);** this area it just direct me in to HardFault_Handler(void) function

Comment: According to the documentation there should be an erase command. https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00122015-description-of-stm32f0-hal-and-lowlayer-drivers-stmicroelectronics.pdf

Comment: yes there is `erase_pages.PageAddress = SoC_Address;
 erase_pages.NbPages = 1;
 erase_pages.TypeErase = FLASH_TYPEERASE_PAGES;
 uint32_t * Error = 0;

 HAL_FLASH_Unlock ();
 HAL_FLASHEx_Erase (&erase_pages, Error);
 HAL_FLASH_Lock ();` when debugging after it enter this line of code it direct me to HardFault_Handler(void) function

Comment: There are some rules you need to follow with flash, for example you can only erase blocks starting at certain addresses. Also you need to turn off interrupts. You also need to make sure that you do not erase the block you are curently running the code at.